# Accessing HDFS parquet files with SparkR on Windows

Tags: r, apache-spark, hadoop, sparkr

From R or RStudio under Windows, I'm trying to access a parquet file in a distant Hadoop cluster:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "C:\\Users\\me\\Hadoop\\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7", HADOOP_HOME = "/opt/hadoop-2.9.0", SPARK_HOME_VERSION="2.3.0" )

.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME" ), "R", "lib" ), .libPaths()))
library(SparkR)
sc <- sparkR.session(enableHiveSupport = FALSE,master = "spark://10.123.45.67:7077", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g" ))

patient <- read.parquet("pseudo/patient" )
```

I know that the connection went fine, as the job appears in the Spark webUI. But when the read.parquet is executed, I get the following error from SparkR:

```
Error: Error in parquet : analysis error - Path does not exist: file:/C:/Users/me/Documents/pseudo/patient;
```

1. What's happening ? What did I forget ?
2. if I use SparkR from the cluster, I need to connect as user hadoop in other to see the data in HDFS. Evidently, in the above code, I didn't connect as hadoop. How do I define access rights to the data for other users ?

Comment: It's reading from your local filesystem. You need to configure the `fs.defaultFS` property to be the remote HDFS address. Also if you're connected to Hadoop, you'd typically set the master to YARN, not a specific IP of a Spark master

Comment: What is the correct syntax ? sc <- sparkR.session(enableHiveSupport = FALSE,master = "spark://10.123.45.67:7077", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g", fs.defaultFS="10.123.45.67" )) gives me a similar error.